# Login with PreparedStatement is not working in Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, console, prepared-statement

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter username: ");
    String un = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    String up = sc.next();
    sc.close();
    try
    {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB",
    "root", "pass");
    String q = "select * from users where username = ? and password = ?";       
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
    ps.setString(1, un);
    ps.setString(2, up);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(q);
    if(rs.next())
        System.out.println("Welcome "+un);
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid username or password");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }

}
```

Getting output as:

```
Enter username: Raja
Enter password: 111
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and password = ?' at line 1
```

Why so? It should work but showing error

Answer (score 4):

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(q);
```

You have to use the no-parameters version, otherwise you're trying to execute the content of your string, not your prepared statement.

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Oh yes.. Thanks dear.. I was not getting what wrong I did